# Dar permiso de sólo impresión con firma digital en Java

Tags: java, pdf

Tengo una duda con dar permiso de sólo impresión a un documento pdf, el código que utilizo:

```
if (pdfFirmadoSellado!=null) {
    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(pdfFirmadoSellado);//documento con firma digital
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader2, new FileOutputStream("D:\\prueba.pdf"));
    stamper.setEncryption(true, null, null,  PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
    stamper.close();
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que el documento "prueba.pdf" sólo tiene permiso para imprimir, pero no genera bien la firma. Sale: "Hay al menos una firma no válida".

Comment: Hola en php he usado la libreria pdftk para darle permisos de impresion a documentos firmados digitalmente. https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

Answer (score 1):

¿Al darle todos los permisos, la firma sí que te la da como válida?

Yo pienso que aunque te indique que hay una firma no válida no se refiere a que la firma esté mal, si no que el *Adobe Reader* (o el que uses) no puede verificar la firma.